# There is a Issue with Uploading a File in Online site form,

Tags: apex, visualforce, force.com-sites, attachment

I have a Online Order form developed through sites, There is a section for Upload a document. When i tried to upload a document that are more than 100 KB it throws the common error UnAuthorized error.

But when I tried to upload 0 to 99 KB it did take me to the next submit page. I the Debug logs it says Unauthorized Successfull. Unable to locate the issue.

Please find the error message.
[image]

Please advise.

I get this error when I upload document more than 100 KB else I get to the submit page.

Comment: Please add the ***verbatim error message*** to your post... Are we supposed to just guess what your error message says? Please [edit] your post to paste it in after a `>` character (to highlight it as a blockquote).

Comment: @AdrianLarson apologise I have updated the error.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best link i came across for debugging issues on Sites:
http://www.tgerm.com/2010/10/debugging-sites-authorization-required.html

I am sure you would be able to know the exact cause of your issue.